# Bigquery query to get sum of values of one column based on another column

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to write a bigquery query to get values of a column which is the sum of values of another column, based on a "like" condition.
In the below table column starts_with_count is what I want to fill. I have added the expected values for this column manually to show my expectation. Other column values are already present.
The starts_with_count value is sum (full_count) where its link appears in other rows.

| company | link | full_count | starts_with_count (expected) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1 | 1 | 15 (= sum (full_count) where link like 'http://www.abc.net1%') |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1/page1 | 2 | 9 (= sum (full_count) where link like 'http://www.abc.net1/page1%') |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1/page1/folder1 | 3 | 3 (= sum (full_count) where link like 'http://www.abc.net1/page1/folder1%') |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1/page1/folder2 | 4 | 4 |
| abc | http://www.abc.net1/page2 | 5 | 5 |
| xyz | http://www.xyz.net1/ | 6 | 21 |
| xyz | http://www.xyz.net1/page1/ | 7 | 15 |
| xyz | http://www.xyz.net1/page1/file1 | 8 | 8 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('abc' AS company, 'http://www.abc.net1' AS link, 1 AS full_count),
    ('abc', 'http://www.abc.net1/page1', 2),
    ('abc', 'http://www.abc.net1/page1/folder1', 3),
    ('abc', 'http://www.abc.net1/page1/folder2', 4),
    ('abc', 'http://www.abc.net1/page2', 5),
    ('xyz', 'http://www.xyz.net1/', 6),
    ('xyz', 'http://www.xyz.net1/page1/', 7),
    ('xyz', 'http://www.xyz.net1/page1/file1', 8)
  ])
)
SELECT first.company, first.link, SUM(second.full_count) AS starts_with_count
  FROM sample first, sample second 
 WHERE STARTS_WITH(second.link, first.link)
 GROUP BY 1, 2
;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @jaytiger - The starts_with() and group by did help in building the query

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
select * except(links),
  ( select sum(full_count)
    from t.links
    where starts_with(link, t.link)
  ) starts_with_count
from (
  select *, 
    array_agg(struct(link, full_count)) over(partition by company) links
  from your_table
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

For the simple/dummy example you provided  - performance improvement is significant!

Which one to use really depends on your `real` data!
To analyze - use `EXECUTION DETAILS` tab

[image]

Comment: Thank you @mikhailberlyant - Really appreciate your advice. 
Now I'm stuck with the performance issue on the query I currently have and need some help.

The above table is called company_totals, that has the following schema -

`company    STRING NULLABLE  
link    STRING NULLABLE  
full_count   FLOAT NULLABLE  
starts_with_count FLOAT NULLABLE`

Number of rows = 12,000,000 
Table size = 1.6 GB 
CLUSTERED BY = company link

Comment: I have the following select statement which is taking beyond 6 hours and the execution results in timeout (Operation timed out after 6.0 hours. Consider reducing the amount of work performed by your operation so that it can complete within this limit.)

`SELECT 
  first_table.company, first_table.link, 
  null as full_count, SUM(second_table.full_count) AS starts_with_count
FROM 
 company_totals first_table, 
 company_totals second_table 
  WHERE STARTS_WITH(second_table.link, first_table.link)
  group by first_table.company, first_table.link`
  
Appreciate any help in this issue.

Comment: I tried the below query -

`select * except(links),
  ( select sum(full_count)
    from t.links
    where starts_with(link, t.link)
  ) starts_with_count
from (
  select *, 
    array_agg(struct(link, full_count)) over(partition by company) links
  from company_totals
)`

I am getting the below error =
`Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 129% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 98% other/unattributed: 2%`

Kindly advice.